# How can I get multiple dataframes with a column containing frequency of elements in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have a list `df_list` with 40 dataframes (elements), where `df_list[[1]]` is the first dataframe of the list and so on.

| id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2345 | 2022-12-01 12:52 |
| 4234 | 2022-12-01 12:52 |
| 2423 | 2022-12-01 12:53 |
| 2434 | 2022-12-01 12:53 |
| 3433 | 2022-12-01 12:53 |
| 5432 | 2022-12-01 13:54 |
| 4534 | 2022-12-01 14:55 |
| 3243 | 2022-12-01 15:55 |

What I expect (new dataframe):

| Frequency | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2022-12-01 12:52 |
| 3 | 2022-12-01 12:53 |
| 1 | 2022-12-01 13:54 |
| 2 | 2022-12-01 15:55 |

I would like to do this for each dataframe in the list and obtain a list of 'new' dataframes.

```
list <- list()
for (i in length(df_list)) {
list[[i]]  <- (count(df_list[[i]], "Date"))
name <- paste("Df",  myfiles_1, sep = "_")
result <- assign(name, list)

}
```

*N.B.* Date column is class `POSIXlt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `my_list` with two data frames, we could:

**Base R:**

```
lapply(my_list, function(x) as.data.frame(table(x$Date)))
```

**dplyr:**

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(my_list, function(x) count(x, Date, name = "Frequency"))
```

**purrr:**

```
library(purrr)
map(my_list, count, Date, name = "Frequency")
```

```
$df1
              Date Frequency
1 2022-12-01 12:52         2
2 2022-12-01 12:53         3
3 2022-12-01 13:54         1
4 2022-12-01 14:55         1
5 2022-12-01 15:55         1

$df2
              Date Frequency
1 2022-12-01 12:42         2
2 2022-12-01 12:43         3
3 2022-12-01 13:44         1
4 2022-12-01 14:45         1
5 2022-12-01 15:45         1
```

list:

```
my_list <- list(df1 = structure(list(id = c(2345L, 4234L, 2423L, 2434L, 
3433L, 5432L, 4534L, 3243L), Date = c("2022-12-01 12:52", "2022-12-01 12:52", 
"2022-12-01 12:53", "2022-12-01 12:53", "2022-12-01 12:53", "2022-12-01 13:54", 
"2022-12-01 14:55", "2022-12-01 15:55")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L)), df2 = structure(list(id = c(2345L, 4234L, 2423L, 2434L, 
3433L, 5432L, 4534L, 3243L), Date = c("2022-12-01 12:42", "2022-12-01 12:42", 
"2022-12-01 12:43", "2022-12-01 12:43", "2022-12-01 12:43", "2022-12-01 13:44", 
"2022-12-01 14:45", "2022-12-01 15:45")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L)))
```

Comment: I have updated the base R version. Now it should work. Be careful using `plyr` and `dplyr` together some verbs interfere. So you have to call some verbs with namespace. I think `mutate` is one of the verbs. So you will need `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: i try again the base r (the new version) and now I have this error: Error in names(dn) <- dnn : 
  'names' attribute [16081] must be the same length as the vector [11]

Comment: i run these libraries : library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)
library(readr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

Comment: Is this the new version: `lapply(my_list, function(x) as.data.frame(table(x$Date)))` If yes then it should work. Does the `purrr` version work for you? Try it with the sample list -> `my_list`.

Comment: i have this error with purrr _ ! unused argument (name = "Frequency"), maybe some packages are in conflict ...

Comment: I tried with the sample list with purrr same error

Comment: OK. I got it: Do it this way: `lapply(my_list, function(x) dplyr::count(x, Date, name = "Frequency"))`

Comment: And the issue is as I suspected with `plyr`. I recommend to restart R and do not load `plyr`!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `dplyr` solution using `bind_rows` and `group_split`:

```r
my_list %>% 
  bind_rows(.id = "df_n") %>% 
  count(Date, df_n, name = "Frequency") %>% 
  group_split(df_n, .keep = FALSE)


#> [[1]]
#>   Date             Frequency
#>   <chr>                <int>
#> 1 2022-12-01 12:52         2
#> 2 2022-12-01 12:53         3
#> 3 2022-12-01 13:54         1
#> 4 2022-12-01 14:55         1
#> 5 2022-12-01 15:55         1
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   Date             Frequency
#>   <chr>                <int>
#> 1 2022-12-01 12:42         2
#> 2 2022-12-01 12:43         3
#> 3 2022-12-01 13:44         1
#> 4 2022-12-01 14:45         1
#> 5 2022-12-01 15:45         1
```

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 rbindlist(my_list, idcol = 'grp')[, .N, .(grp, Date)]
```